# Capture scrolling window screenshot in macOS

Tags: gratis, macos, screenshot

Is there any software which can take a scrolling window screenshot? For example, I want to take the screenshot of Terminal which has more content than what is visible in the screen (I am aware of the FSCapture app in Windows which used to work fine for vertical scrollbars though it does not work for both vertical and horizontal scrollbars. I did not find any alternative for macOS.)

The default screenshot tool of macOS only captures what is visible on the screen. The only other option I have is to go for "screen recording" which is not really a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Just pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in Terminal already saves the complete output to a text file. It does not preserve colours though. See below for a short output example.

```
Last login: Thu Oct 14 19:42:28 on ttys000
gerwin@Gerwins-MacBook ~ % pwd
/Users/gerwin
gerwin@Gerwins-MacBook ~ % cd /
gerwin@Gerwins-MacBook / %
```